# Morris.js bar chart not displaying evey xkey

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I have been using Morris.js And have set xkey. `Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, 'Oct', Nov, Dec`

I am using bootstrap col-lg-6 like

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="bar-example"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Morris.Bar({
      element: 'bar-example',
      resize: true,
      stacked: true,
      grid: true,
      gridTextSize: 10,
      data: [
        { m: 'Jan', a: 1},
        { m: 'Feb', a: 2},
        { m: 'Mar', a: 3},
        { m: 'Apr', a: 4},
        { m: 'May', a: 5},
        { m: 'Jun', a: 15},
        { m: 'Jul', a: 7},
        { m: 'Aug', a: 8},
        { m: 'Sept', a: 9},
        { m: 'Oct', a: 10},
        { m: 'Nov', a: 11},
        { m: 'Dec', a: 12}
        ],
        xkey: 'm',
        ykeys: ['a'],
        labels: ['New Users']
    });
}); 
</script>
```

But for some reason when I am using smaller columns of bootstrap the bar chart does not display all of the xkey

xkey. `, Feb, , Apr, , Jun, , Aug, , Nov, Dec`

It Seems to miss some of the months when in smaller columns of bootstrap

Here is the codepen example [Code View](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/YWrjEp) and [Full View](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/YWrjEp/)

> **Question** How is it possible when have smaller bar chart to display all of the xkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a frustrating issue with no real solution, but you can try this:

Add `xLabelAngle: 60` to your Morris options:

```
Morris.Bar({
      ...
      xLabelAngle: 60,
      ...
});
```

This will turn the label angle, which forces Morris to render the xkeys. For some reason, it interprets smaller widths to mean a lack of space for the xkeys even though we can clearly see there is enough room for all of the xkeys.

Another option is to decrease the `gridTextSize` although I tried it in your CodePen and don't recommend it since the xkeys are not legible.